# All pages load the home page if pretty permalinks are used

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I'm trying to help a buddy out -- his site, on a fresh WordPress install, is behaving oddly.   With default permalinks set, everything works, but with pretty permalinks set up, all of the pages on the navigation bar load as the home page.

If you hover over them, the links are still in the original `?page_id=x` form....

Any ideas why this is happening?

Hosting is with [Go Daddy](https://www.godaddy.com/) and they are singularly unhelpful.

Many thanks.

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, GoDaddy has been notorious for problems while setting up pretty permalinks for the first time. Are you working with a Windows or Linux GoDaddy server?

The following sites may be of some help, but from what I've read you may need to have somebody at GoDaddy make changes for you if you do not have sufficient privileges.

- http://www.wpressurecooker.com/permalinks/2009/08/24/pretty-permalinks-with-godaddy-windows-hosting/
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pretty-permalink-trouble
- http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/pretty-permalinks-not-working

Comment: Hey Evan -- thanks for the links.  The weird thing is that most of the godaddy issues (i've been doing my homework) are 404  related -- is you type nonsense beyond the last / you'll get to a 404 page, which suggests that this is...something else?